# WPF combobox binding null value

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a wpf combo box that is bound to an `IEnumerable` collection in my view model. When the combobox is first bound, null is selected. When selecting any other value in the combobox, the null disappears.  Is there a way to have the null value remain without altering the collection?

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CarCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar}"
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding CarName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"                                 
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot have `null` be an option unless it is actually in the list.

You can of course set the backing property to `null` which should clear the UI selection. If you *need* a null property, without modifying the list in the view model, consider using `CompositeCollection`. With it, you can do something like:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ComboBoxItems">
    <CompositeCollection>
       <ListViewItem>Pick a choice</ListViewItem>
       <CollectionContainer Source="{Binding MyCollection}"/>
    </CompositeCollection>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

A full example can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection(v=vs.110).aspx).